# SQL Запрос с выборкой

Tags: c#, sql, access

Извините если неправильно пишу вопрос,новуенький просто!
У меня есть база данных, в ней есть таблица Children, где находится их возраст
И есть таблица People,таблицы связаны( в children есть айди родителя из таблицы people)

Как мне создать запрос что бы вывело людей из people у которых дети возрастом от 10 до 15 лет?

Comment: Можно отфильтровать детей по диапазону возраста и взять у них distinct id родителей, только причем тут c# и access?

Comment: Приложение для обработки данных на c# использую бд access

Comment: `where people.id = child.parent_id and child.age between 10 and 15`